# Hide TabView on subview

Tags: swiftui, tabview

I have a little problem. I have a bottom Tab bar which visible everywhere. But I want to hide tab view only in one view (MessageView). How to do that?

My TabView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabBarView: View {
    @AppStorage("isDarkMode") var isDarkMode: Bool = false
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Group {
                    ContactsView(isDarkMode: $isDarkMode)
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "person")
                            Text("Contacts")
                        }
                        .tag(0)
                    
                    CallsView(isDarkMode: $isDarkMode)
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "phone")
                            Text("Calls")
                        }
                        .tag(1)
                    
                    ChatsView(isDarkMode: $isDarkMode)
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "bubble.left")
                            Text("Chats")
                        }
                        .tag(2)
                    
                    SettingsView()
                        .environmentObject(AuthViewModel())
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                            Text("Settings")
                        }
                        .tag(3)
                }
                .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar)
            }
    }
}

struct TabBarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var mockSelectedTab = 2
    static var previews: some View {
        TabBarView(selectedTab: $mockSelectedTab)
    }
}
```

Here is my ChatView where navigates to MessageView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChatsView: View {
    @Binding var isDarkMode: Bool
    @State private var isEditing = false
    @State private var selectedContacts: Set<UUID> = []
    @State private var showNewMessageSheet = false
    
    var contacts = [
        Contact(name: "Alice", avatar: "", messages: [Message(text: "Hi", timestamp: Date())]),
        Contact(name: "Bob", avatar: "", messages: [Message(text: "Hello", timestamp: Date())])
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List(selection: $selectedContacts) {
                ForEach(contacts) { contact in
                    NavigationLink(destination: MessageView(isDarkMode: $isDarkMode, contact: contact)) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(contact.avatar)
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(contact.name)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                
                                Text(contact.messages.last?.text ?? "")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text(formatDate(contact.messages.last?.timestamp ?? Date()))
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                    .tag(contact.id)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    if isEditing {
                        Button("Done", action: {
                            isEditing.toggle()
                        })
                    } else {
                        Button("Edit", action: {
                            isEditing.toggle()
                        })
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    if isEditing {
                        HStack {
                            Button("Archive", action: {
                                // Archive action
                            })
                            
                            Button("Delete", action: {
                                // Delete action
                            })
                            .disabled(selectedContacts.isEmpty)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Button(action: {
                            showNewMessageSheet.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(isDarkMode ? AnyView(DarkMode()) : AnyView(LightMode()))
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarTitle("Chats", displayMode: .inline)
            .environment(\.editMode, .constant(isEditing ? EditMode.active : EditMode.inactive))
            .onAppear {
                self.isEditing = false
            }
        }
        .environment(\.colorScheme, isDarkMode ? .dark : .light)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showNewMessageSheet) {
            ContactsView(isDarkMode: $isDarkMode)
        }
    }
}



struct ChatsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var isDarkMode = false
    static var previews: some View {
        ChatsView(isDarkMode: $isDarkMode)
    }
}
```

My MessageView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MessageView: View {
    @State private var messageText: String = ""
    @State private var isMicButton: Bool = true
    @Binding var isDarkMode: Bool
    
    var contact: Contact
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                // List of messages
            }
            .onTapGesture {hideKeyboard()}
            // Message Input Area
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    // Add Media Action
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                }

                TextField("Type a message", text: $messageText)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(.horizontal)

                if messageText.isEmpty {
                    Button(action: {
                        if isMicButton {
                            // Send Audio Message
                        } else {
                            // Send Video Message
                        }
                        isMicButton.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: isMicButton ? "mic.fill" : "video.fill")
                    }
                } else {
                    Button(action: {
                        // Send Text Message
                        messageText = ""
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .background(isDarkMode ? AnyView(DarkMode()) : AnyView(LightMode()))
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text(contact.name)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text("Last Active: Today")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Text(contact.avatar)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct MessageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var isDarkMode = false
    static var previews: some View {
        MessageView(isDarkMode: $isDarkMode, contact: Contact(name: "Alice", avatar: "", messages: [Message(text: "Hi", timestamp: Date())]))
    }
}
```

I tried to use .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar). But it hides tabView everywhere. Thanks in advance

I tried to use .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar). But it hides tabView everywhere. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** As Ray suggested

It can be simply achieved by wrapping `TabView` itself inside `NavigationStack`. Here is a simplified code:

```
struct TabBarView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView {
                SubView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                        Text("Contacts")
                    }

                SubView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "phone")
                        Text("Calls")
                    }

                SubView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "bubble.left")
                        Text("Chats")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}



struct SubView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildView()) {
                Text("Go to ChildView")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(8)

            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("ChildView")
    }

}

#Preview {
    TabBarView()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes but I will correct my question. This view where I want to hide tab bar is navigated view from tab view. So this is the subview

Comment: I just cant see where MessageView and TabBarView interact

Comment: Oh, I see. I updated my main q. Can you please look that? I put ChatView code where navigates to MessageView. I tried wrap tabView in NavigationView and it worked. But after that NavBar items of ChatView duplicated in other views.

Comment: check the answer now, I just updated it

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer you are the best. But, I found simple solution for that and can you confirm that it's good to practice? I wrapped TabView in NavigationStack and in other views use NavigationView. So tab bar is hided successfully

Comment: great, your way works too.  it just depends how you want bottom tab bar disappear and appear